# Set value of combo box to collected value from source

Tags: c#, database, forms

I have a form with two combo boxes which both have a list from a database. In this case one is a list of countries and based on the value selected there, the second list is updated to show only the cities that belong to the selected country. After that, the values are combined and stored in my program like "city, country".

When I open my form I retrieve that information and separate the values back to just country and city. All working. The trouble I have now is that the comboboxes should display the retrieved values if the correspond to a value found in the list/database. I tried as shown below, but that is not working. I guess it has something to do with adding a new row to the database to show "--Select Country--" and "--Select City--".

I hope you can point me in the right direction. Thank you all in advance for your replies.

```
comboBoxCountry.SelectedValue = comboBoxCountry.FindString(country);
comboBoxCity.SelectedValue = comboBoxCity.FindString(city);
```

```
public partial class FormPropertyEditor : Form
    {
        //Connect to local database.mdf
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + 
            @"C:\Users\gleonvanlier\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\MHS Property Editor\Database.mdf;" +
            "Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=False;");

        DataRow dr;

    public FormPropertyEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReadProperties();
            refreshdata();
        }

    public void refreshdata()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TblCountries Order by CountryName", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "--Select Country--" };
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
            comboBoxCountry.ValueMember = "CountryID";
            comboBoxCountry.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
            comboBoxCountry.DataSource = dt;
            comboBoxCountry.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            comboBoxCountry.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        }


        private void comboBoxCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBoxCountry.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
            {
                int CountryID = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxCountry.SelectedValue.ToString());
                refreshstate(CountryID);
            }
        }

        public void refreshstate(int CountryID)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TblCities where CountryID= @CountryID Order by CityName", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CountryID", CountryID);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, 0, "--Select City--" };
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

            comboBoxCity.ValueMember = "CityID";
            comboBoxCity.DisplayMember = "CityName";
            comboBoxCity.DataSource = dt;
            comboBoxCity.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            comboBoxCity.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        }

    private void ReadProperties()
        {
            string progId = "Inventor.Application";
            Type inventorApplicationType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progId);

            Inventor.Application invApp = (Inventor.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject(progId);

            //Get the active document in Inventor
            Document oDoc = (Document)invApp.ActiveDocument;

            ReadProperties readProperties = new ReadProperties();

            //Read Customer
            string txtCustomer = readProperties.ReadCustomProperty("Customer", oDoc).ToString();
            this.textBoxCustomer.Text = txtCustomer;

            //Read Location
            string txtLocation = readProperties.ReadCustomProperty("Location", oDoc).ToString();

            try
            {
                string[] location = txtLocation.Split(',', ' ');
                string city = location[0];
                string country = location[1];
                comboBoxCountry.SelectedValue = comboBoxCountry.FindString(country);
                comboBoxCity.SelectedValue = comboBoxCity.FindString(city);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string city = string.Empty;
                string country = string.Empty;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it:

```
comboBoxCountry.SelectedIndex = comboBoxCountry.FindStringExact(country);
comboBoxCity.SelectedIndex = comboBoxCity.FindStringExact(city);
```